# Не приходят данные в метод $.ajax success в ie 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, explorer

В ie 9 в success метод приходят два параметра: `textStatus` и `XMLHttpRequest`. `Data` всегда `undefined`. Во всех других браузерах код работает нормально и в success приходят 3 параметра. В итоге, я не могу обработать ни один ajax-запрос, после того как он выполнился. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот часть кода метода:

```
SendAjax = function(async, type, act, t, datas)
{
    var datatype = 'html';
    if (type=='reload_weather' || type=='popup' || act == 'set_location')
        datatype = 'json';


    var result = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: '_ajax/',
        data: {act:act, type:type, datas:datas},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: datatype,
        cache: false,
        async: async,
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            printArray(arguments);
            /*
             {
                 "1": "success",
                 "2": {
                 "readyState": 4,
                 "status": 200,
                 "statusText": "OK"
                 }
             }
             */

            printArray(data);
            /*
                undefined
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax-запрос данные получает и текст ответа в отладчике ie я могу посмотреть. Там то, что мне нужно. Но как их мне обработать в коде и почему они не появляются в методе success?

**UPDATE:** проблема решена путем добавления в php-файл, куда отправляется запрос, строки:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: printArray() это что ? может в нем дело ? например нет каких нить методов Array.prototype ?

Comment: Покажите код метода `printArray`.

Comment: Проблема не в нем. Это просто вывод на консоль. Под методом я указал, что он выводит.
function printArray(array) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(array, null, 4));
}

. Также я могу посмотреть результат запроса в Fiddler. Тексты ответа есть всегда. В ie7 и 8 также не работает, data и соответственно responseText всегда undefined. В Chrome, Safari, Opera, FF все работает...

Comment: Попробуйте воткнуть `debugger` в `success` и пробежаться по стеку вверх, может что-то увидите.